# When i do search a turkish word,it doesn't highlighted but english it does

Tags: php, regex

I have a live search script made with ajax and php.
It used to search with english characters with this regex :

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
```

If the search matches ,the word highlighted.

I want to search with turkish characters  so i change the regex code this :

```
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9ğıüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
```

It perfectly search,but after changing this code,if turkish code find ,it doesn't higlighted but english it does.

This is highlight  code :

```
// Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
$display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i",                            "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_adi']);
$display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>",$result['musteri_telefon']) ;
$display_url = urlencode($result['musteri_id']);
$display_mail = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_mail']);
$display_tcno = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['musteri_tcno']);
```

I think i should change the highlighted code but i don't know how to do

Comment: Try: `$search_string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9ğıüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ]/u', " ", $_POST['query']);`

Comment: @anubhava it is still the same but thanks

Comment: any sample string ? if you get a match in return, there is something with highlighting not with regex.

Comment: It seems there is some problem with the highlighting code, since the regex and *preg_replace* [act as expected](https://ideone.com/eDLOFJ). Without knowing specific input you have trouble with, it is difficult to pinpoint the root cause. See [this](https://ideone.com/a6ZXeS).

Comment: @stribizhev: **Never process Unicode text without `u` flag**: https://ideone.com/vHHOFf You get the result simply because the bytes are included in the character class. I crafted the string based on the bytes of the characters in character class when encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @NeverHopeless i search 'aysu' it is highlighted and i search 'Çınar ', it is not highlighted

Comment: @AysuVural: Perhaps, the problem is that you replace unwanted characters with a space. Try removing them completely with `$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9ğıüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ]/u", "", $keyword);`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/1SvOWi).

Comment: @AysuVural, and you get a match from regex engine for both cases ?

Comment: @stribizhev thanks it work now

Comment: @AysuVural: I will post my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main points here to take into consideration:

1. The regex should be declared with a `/u` modifier to enable full Unicode support
2. The replacement you perform replaces unwanted characters with a space, while you can remove them completely with `$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9ğıüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ]/u", "", $keyword);`

See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/1SvOWi):

```
$keyword = 'Çınar ';
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9ğıüşöçİĞÜŞÖÇ]/u", "", $keyword);
echo $search_string . PHP_EOL;
$musteri_adi = "Çınar, more and more words.";
$display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $musteri_adi);
echo $display_name . PHP_EOL;
```